# How to create dynamic value in WP_Query meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need to pass dynamic value in to the value key in the meta_query array in the wp_query. Is it possible to pass the dynamic value in the query. 
My Code is

```
$prodPost = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'paged'             => 1,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'relation'  => 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_last_date',
            'value'     => date('d-m-Y'),
            'compare'   => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_limit',
            'value'     => $limit,
            'compare'   => '>',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

As you see in my query i need to query the product which satisfies both condition, but the problem with second condition is that I need to pass the `$limit` value dynamically for the corresponding product post. Is there any to accomplish this query. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you're trying to do. I think the issue may be that `relation` should not be contained in it's own array. It should look like this:

```
$prodPost = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'paged'             => 1,
    'meta_query'        => array( array(
        'relation'  => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_last_date',
            'value'     => date('d-m-Y'),
            'compare'   => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_limit',
            'value'     => $limit,
            'compare'   => '>',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

If it's still not working at that point I would verify your meta keys are the correct keys and `$limit` holds the expected value.

---

See [Initializing Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query) for more examples.